# Failed: Copy Module 'GeneXusJWT'

Tags: genexus

Estoy actualizando modules en Genexus **17**, desde la opción **Knowledge Manager - Manage Module References**.

Actualizo en particular 2 módulos: GenexusJWT y SecuritiAPICommons.

Luego de actualizarlos, doy "Run" en las opciones de build y obtengo el error **Failed: Copy Module 'GeneXusJWT'**

Intenté cerrar Genexus, abrí Símbolo de sistema de windows y ejecuté *Genexus.exe /install* pero continúa apareciendo el error.

Es con el módulo GenexusJWT, SecurityAPICommons es copiado correctamente.

Build output:
*========== Copy Module 'SecurityAPICommons' started ==========

Success: Copy Module 'SecurityAPICommons'

========== Copy Module 'GeneXusJWT' started ==========

Failed: Copy Module 'GeneXusJWT'*

¿Cómo solucionar este error?
Versión GX17, generador Java.

Comment: Cuando lo instalás desde el MM  te da error? Lo estás instalando desde local o Global Matrix?
Si cuando lo instalas no da error, probaría con el log de Genexus a ver si aporta más información. En https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?23257,GeneXus%20Log explica como.

O en el event viewer de la máquina si indica porqué no puede copiar ese modulo.

En mi caso en el log dice:
2023-09-14 13:46:40,338 [1] DEBUG GeneXus - Installing module 'C:\Program Files (x86)\GeneXus\GeneXus17U11\modules\GeneXusJWT_2.11.35.163500.opc'

Comment: Gracias @Guscarr. En el archivo GXLogging.log pude ver el mensaje ERROR GeneXus - Access to the path 'D:\PathToFile\file' is denied.
Revisando el archivo, veo que estaba como archivo oculto en Windows. Quitando la propiedad "oculto", ya no hay problemas al copiar los archivos jar. Lo raro es que ocurre con la propiedad "oculto" de los archivos de windows, si hubiera sido con la propiedad "Sólo Lectura" hubiese tenido más sentido.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comento cómo solucioné:

En el archivo **GXLogging.log** se observó el siguiente mensaje:

```
 Access to the path 'D:\ExamplePath\JavaModel\web\drivers\java-jwt-3.10.3.jar' is denied.
```

Revisando las propiedades del archivo en Windows, se encontraba como archivo "oculto". Ni siquiera se encontraba como "Sólo Lectura".

Quitando la propiedad "oculto" de Windows al archivo, al hacer Build ya no ocurre el error Failed: Copy Module 'GeneXusJWT'.